# Get your B&CG Hats!

Tags: discussion

The hat bash is on and B&CG is participating!

Check it out via the link on the top bar, or go to http://winterba.sh/

If you don't like them, you can turn 'em off.

Comment: sooo you already have a hat.. why are you not wearing it???

Comment: @gbianchi looks like hats only show on the [main site](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/40/pat-ludwig).  A tad disappointing.

Comment: I hope this will not start a meta post race to get the hat :)...

Comment: @gbianchi - fortunately I got mine before you warned against it!!

Comment: Now I've got to do something to replace this [stupid looking cake](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/50/ire-and-curses)...

Comment: @ire_and_curses - there's always something to do around here :)

Comment: Wow, Winter Bash does *not* like Chrome. The tab just loads forever (without a warning about out-of-control scripts).

Comment: Nevermind; updated Chrome, winterba.sh happy now. Obviously, I blame the cat I don't have.